# How do I use knowledgebase for Dialogflow in C#

Tags: c#, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am trying to follow [this](https://dialogflow.com/docs/agents/knowledge-connectors) example to setup knowledge base using `Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2` in C#

If I understand correctly, the docs say add the following to my intent request:

```
'queryParams': {
  'knowledgeBaseNames': ['projects/my-gcp-project/knowledgeBases/my-knowledge-base-id']
}
```

In my c# project I'm stuggling to map this to the properties I have as shown here:
[image]

Could anyone please provide me with assistance if they've done this before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Knowledge connectors are currently in beta - they're part of the V2Beta1 API, but not part of the V2 API. (For the gory details, you can compare the API definitions we build the libraries from [in GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google/cloud/dialogflow)).

I'm afraid we currently don't build a library for the Dialogflow V2Beta1 API in C#.

That leaves your options as:

- Wait for Knowledge connectors to make it into the V2 API (and for us to regenerate the V2 library). This is probably the simplest approach, to be honest.
- Use a language that *does* support the V2Beta1 API. From the [documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks), it looks like this is Node, Java and Python.
- Build a library for the Dialogflow V2Beta1 API yourself. This is definitely feasible (and if you clone the [google-cloud-dotnet repo](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet), edit `generateapis.sh` to include it, run that script, then edit `apis/apis.json` to give project details then run `generateprojects.sh` it *might* just work... but it's not terribly pleasant if you aren't familiar with the tooling we use.

Sorry not to be able to give you any more encouraging news than that, but at least it's an explanation of what you're seeing...

Comment: Sad that there's seemingly no movement on this over 4 years later. That's a long time for a feature to be in beta!

Comment: @PhilipStratford: Well, there's "movement" in that we now do publish a NuGet package for the beta version: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2Beta1/1.0.0-beta08